# How can I add "data-target" additional attribute in mega menu?

Tags: 8, navigation

How can I add an additional attribute to menu item I am using mega menu?

On element inspect my current menu url is displaying as :

```
<a class="we-mega-menu-li activeNav" title=""href="/clients/drupal/abc/fr/home#xyz" target="">
 something
</a>
```

I need to create it as :

```
<a class="we-mega-menu-li activeNav" title=""  data-target="xyz" href="/clients/drupal/abc/fr/home#xyz" target="">
 something
</a>
```

I have used **menu links attribute** module but its not working with mega menu 
any other suggestions by doing some custom code?

Comment: Is it dynamically generating menu or static menu?

Comment: its is static menu only

Answer (score 0):

You can use below code to set attributes. This will add an attribute to all links in the page. But make sure to add the condition check for your URL.

```
/**
 * Implements template_preprocess_menu().
 */
function THEME_preprocess_menu(&$variables) {
  foreach ($variables['items'] as $item) {
    $item['attributes']->setAttribute('data-target', 'YOUR TARGET NAME');
  }
}
```

Comment: Sorry its not working for my case

Answer (score 0):

Finally i found the solution by myself:

I have copied the twig file from **mega menu** module to our theme's directory **we-megamenu-li.html.twig** and make the following changes into it, now data- target values are dynamic .

```
<a class="we-mega-menu-li"   data-target="{{ href | split('#')[1] }}"   title="{{ attribute(attributes, 'description') }}" href="{{ href }}" target="{{ attribute(attributes, 'data-target') }}">something
</a>
```